# How to change text of the top left cell of a datagridview?

Tags: c#, user-interface, datagridview

I need the cell of the top left corner of this datagridview to have the value "id" instead of making a column for id.

any help please.

[image]

Comment: Where are you getting the data that fills it from? Are you unable to add a line to it? Also, do you just want to add "id" to that one cell, or do you also want to shift all other cells down?

Comment: how do you expect the ID column to hold the values of `1, 2,3, 4 ,etc...` perhaps you mean you want the `ID Column` to be named something else.. if that's the case then change your query to SELECT ID AS RecNum, Column1 ,Column2, Column3, ...etc`

Comment: @furkle, answer of the first question :this is just an example of what i need 
answer of the second question :yes I need to just add "id" to this cell

Comment: @DJ KRAZE I use a foreach loop to add the id number
foreach ( DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows )
                {
                    row.HeaderCell.Value = (row.Index+1).ToString();
                }

Comment: then just add a condition if the first iteration = 0 for example then set the text to what ever you want instead of using the index then set the rest = to `Column + index.ToString()`

Comment: @furkle , How to hide the small triangle in the row header ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably need to set up the [`DataGridView.TopLeftHeaderCell`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.topleftheadercell(v=vs.110).aspx) property:

```
dataGridView1.TopLeftHeaderCell.Value = "ID";
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
Is there a way to hide the small triangle in the row header ?

Comment: @MohamedSalah I don't think there is a simple way. Why not just hide row headers at all?

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me (after reading your comments) like you'd be better off keeping the ID column the way it is, rather than trying to reuse the "row headers" column and override its functionality.

Just hide the "row headers" column:

```
dataGridView1.RowHeadersVisible = false;
```

If you still want to be able to select the entire row, similar to clicking on the row header column, you can change the selection mode:

```
dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
```

Comment: good thinking, but can I set Enabled property of the hole IDColumn to be false ? (to have unselectable property ?